# Is is possible to add a variable to a python filter, including the iterable?

Tags: python, filter

I have a filter that gets an iterable and I wanted to know if its possible to add another value to it which is not part of the iterable.

My filter is very simple and looks like:

```
def filter_something(line):
     return (line['something1'] == 'something1' and line['something2'] == 'something2')
```

I am using the above filter to create a new filtered list:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(filter_something, unfiltered_list))
```

I would like to add another value to the filter but the value is not part of the iterable itself, so my imaginary filter_something would look something like:

```
def filter_something(line, animal):
     if animal == "cat":
        return line['something1'] == 'something1' 
     if animal == "dog":
        return line['something2'] == 'something2' 
return false
```

and the way I (optimistically) imagine the filter usage to look like would be:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(filter_something("dog"), unfiltered_list))
```

The above imaginary code obviously doesn't work but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: `filter(lambda i: filter_something(i, existence), ...)`…?

Comment: Could you include some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As, @deceze suggested, you can use lambda, or you can use functools.partial to achieve this:

```
from functools import partial

def filter_something(line, do_i_exist):
     if do_i_exist:
        return False
     return (line == 1 or line == 2)

unfiltered_list = [1,2,3]

existence = False
filter_partial = partial(filter_something, do_i_exist = existence)

filtered_list = list(filter(filter_partial, unfiltered_list))
print(filtered_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question to be more precise as I might have mislead you.  I  tried your solution and I am getting the following behavior - When I actually get into the filter stage after partial,  the line value is the string ("dog" in my case) while animal is the dictionary. (it should be the other way around.) What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @PloniStacker Did you specify animal as a keyword argument for partial (`animal = "dog"`, not simply `partial(filter_something, "dog")`)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you @matszwecja and @deceze for your helpful direction and guidance! I ended up using lambda function in the following manner:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda filtered_row: filter_something(filtered_row, animal), unfiltered_list))
```

I believe that combining lambda function with this type of filter requirement is the most elegant and straight forward.